# Padding in CSS is not working

Tags: html, css, padding

here is my code
for some reason I can't get text on the picture, why is that?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ilo.css">
  <title>Drum World</title>
</head>
<body background="back.jpg">
  <center><strong><font face="arial" size="10" color="#3366CC">Perfect Gallery     OF         Drums!    </font></strong>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#006666"><strong><center>Enjoy viewing all    sorts    of drums</center></strong></font>
  </br>
  </br>
  <img src="pearl drum.jpg" border="5px">
  <p id="txt">TEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
  </img>
```

and here is CSS:

```css
#txt {
  padding: 15px 35px 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, the center and font tags? I fee like I'm back in the 90's.

Comment: you should update your HTML code, it is HTML deprecated

Comment: I'm aware of the issues, Thanks but can anyone offer solution?

Comment: I love the closing _<br>_ and _<img>_ tags. It's like you're creating your own markup language.

Comment: @user3550204 If I had to guess what your issue was, I'd lean towards invalid markup. Try fixing your HTML and see if that resolves your CSS issues.

Comment: Hi Brian, my issue is that I can't get padding to work, I want the "TEXTTEXTTEXT" to appear on a photo, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: use the image as background instead.

Comment: You can't use p tag in img tag.

Answer (score 1):

if you want "text" to be on the picture, you could give your img a relative positioning and the p an absolute positioning. 
Also, fix your html tags they are deprecated and messed up >.<.

http://jsfiddle.net/GNkKL/

```
img{
    position:relative;
}

#txt
{
padding: 15px 35px 5px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Just deleted my answer... I like this way better. ^^^

Comment: Thank you, You've helped a lot :^)